# How to make long truncated behind text of long text, not front text in TextField?

Tags: flutter

I use `TextFormField` in flutter.

And I need to record speech and show that text on it with below code.

```
    _messageController.text = result.recognizedWords;
```

But the problem is is case that text is long.

For example text is `Hi my name is may. I want to drink coke, since I'm thirsty'

Since TextFormField has width, It shows only front part like `Hi my name is may. I want`.

But I want to show behind part, not front part.

I also set `selection` for this.

```
 _messageController.text = result.recognizedWords;
    _messageController.selection =
        TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _messageController.text.length);
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there any solution for this?